# view swift interface for Objc file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am working in a mixed ObjC Swift project. I am currently overriding functions that where written in ObjC in a swift subclass. I'm wondering if there is a quick way to view the auto generated Swift header files for the objC file so that I can check the syntax of functions after they have been converted to swift.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a quick way to view the auto generated Swift header files for the objC

Switch to the Generated Interface in the first menu of the jump bar.

[image]

Example: **before:**

[image]

**after:**

[image]